# why c language get same type and same address, but get different answer?

Tags: c, pointers

this is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>

int* toInt(int number);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *b;

    b = toInt(123);

    printf("result %p \n", b);
    printf("result %d \n", *b);

    return 0;
}

int * toInt(int number)
{
    int* tmp = &number;

    printf("toInt %p \n", tmp);
    printf("toInt %d \n", *tmp);

    return tmp;
}
```

and this is get answer,

```
toInt 0x7ffeebb2215c 
toInt 123 
result 0x7ffeebb2215c 
result 329262780
```

in this case, in function toInt and in main, it get same address： 0x7ffeebb2215c  , and same type： int, but the value is different。

i dont know。 it works in golang

Comment: Go and C have different lifecycle rules.

Comment: The code invokes *undefined behavior* anyway so I'd not worry/wonder about it much.

Comment: You return a pointer to a local variable which has gone out of scope.  All bets about what happens are off.